# How to store "no value" fields in Apache IoTDB to reach query returned results faster?

Tags: sum, apache-iotdb, iotdb

For fields that need to do `sum` in Apache IoTDB, should we store no value fileds in `null` or in 0 to return the query results faster in Apache IoTDB? I am using aligned time series and I need to query one specific field in each time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, if you use aligned time series in Apache IoTDB, both null and 0 will be queried in the same time, Null will be treated automatically as 0 when doing `sum` calculation.